# Unable to install web3.js into my system(WINDOWS 10)

Tags: web3js, contract-development, geth-debugging, npm, authentication

**CMD show this error message  **
Geth and python is installed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you copy-paste Git URL, use https:// instead of ssh://

Or, alternative, add SSH key to your SSH agent, probably using command `ssh-add`. This really depends on course instructions and this question should be addressed to whoever is running the course, not a public forum.

Comment: send command please

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** installing from the official repo. From the image you are installing `npm install etherium/web3.js` (there's a typo *etherium*).

The web3 project started from Ethereum organization, but it is now being developed by ChainSafe. The official [readme](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js#readme) indicates `npm install web3` for installing.

```
npm install web3
```

Comment: E:\studentSample>npm install web3

up to date, audited 384 packages in 2s

53 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

1 low severity vulnerability

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: @AmmaraDeveloper So it installed correctly. There is a low severity vulnerability, that usually shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: then why still I am unable to install web3.js

Comment: @AmmaraDeveloper The message says that web3 is already installed. You should be able to use it. If you can't use web3 update the question or create a new one, after looking the site for existing answers.